# How do I solve Cypress plugin error when running a test?

Tags: windows, cypress

I am just starting with Cypress and when I run a very simple test, the browser is getting closed and I get an error.

I checked the index.js file and its looks ok.
Am I missing something?

[image]

Index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {}
```

Comment: Do you import something in your `index.js` file?

Comment: no, nothing. you can see the it in the question